# How to continue after receiving None response from xml parse

Tags: python, xml, beautifulsoup

I am finding prices of products from Amazon using their API with Bottlenose and parsing the xml response with BeautifulSoup. 
I have a predefined list of products that the code iterates through.
This is my code:

```
import bottlenose as BN
import lxml
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

i = 0
amazon = BN.Amazon('myid','mysecretkey','myassoctag',Region='UK',MaxQPS=0.9)
list = open('list.txt', 'r')

print "Number", "New Price:","Used Price:"

for line in list:
    i = i + 1
    listclean = line.strip()
    response = amazon.ItemLookup(ItemId=listclean, ResponseGroup="Large")

    soup = BeautifulSoup(response, "xml")

    usedprice=soup.LowestUsedPrice.Amount.string
    newprice=soup.LowestNewPrice.Amount.string
    print i , newprice, usedprice
```

This  works fine and will run through my list of amazon products until it gets to a product which doesn't have any value for that set of tags, [like no new/used price.](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Mathematical-Methods-Physical-Sciences-Mary-x/dp/0471198269/ref=sr_1_3?ie=UTF8&qid=1454924392&sr=8-3&keywords=boas)

At which Python will throw up this response:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'Amount'
```

Which makes sense as there is no tags/string found by BS that I searched for. Having no value is perfectly fine from what I'm trying to achieve, however the code collapses at this point and will not continue.

I have tried:

```
if soup.LowestNewPrice.Amount != None:
    newprice=soup.LowestNewPrice.Amount.string
else:
    continue
```

and also tried:

```
newprice=0
if soup.LowestNewPrice.Amount != 0:
    newprice=soup.LowestNewPrice.Amount.string
else:
    continue
```

I am at a loss for how to continue after receiving the nonetype value return. Unsure whether the problem lies fundamentally in the language or in the libraries I'm using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use exception handling:

```
try:
    # operation which causes AttributeError
except AttributeError:
    continue
```

The code in the try block will be executed and if an AttributeError is raised, the execution will immediately drop into the except block (which will cause the next item in the loop to be ran).  If no error is raised, the code will happily skip the except block.

---

If you just wish to set the missing values to zero and print, you can do

```
try: newprice=soup.LowestNewPrice.Amount.string
except AttributeError: newprice=0

try: usedprice=soup.LowestUsedPrice.Amount.string
except AttributeError: usedprice=0

print i , newprice, usedprice
```

Comment: This works and will allow the code to continue. However the code will completely skip the entire loop, so if there is no used price it will skip finding the new price too. Ideally what I'd like is if there is a 'None' response, is for the value called to just be set to equal zero. Is there a way to do this with exceptions?

Comment: To clarify, I just tried this. `try:
        newprice=soup.LowestNewPrice.Amount.string
    except AttributeError:
        newprice=0
        continue`

This will continue the program if None type is returned, but it will skip the entire for loop iteration and move to the next item in my list.

Comment: @AstroDavid I added to the answer to address how you can just set the values equal to zero and continue on.  Note that the `continue` expression means to move on to the next loop index, so you don't want to use that in this case.  See [the python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) for more on exception handling.

Comment: Oh nice, I removed `continue` from the exception and now it works.  Excellent, thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way of comparing with None is `is None`, not `== None` or `is not None`, not `!= None`.

Secondly, you also need to check `soup.LowestNewPrice` for None, not the `Amount`, i.e.:

```
if soup.LowestNewPrice is not None:
    ... read soup.LowestNewPrice.Amount
```

Comment: Changing the line to be : 
    `if soup.LowestNewPrice.Amount is not None:

     newprice = soup.LowestNewPrice.Amount`
still throws up the Nonetype response.